# Can't perform the slicing operation with Blender's boolean modifier

Tags: modeling, modifiers

I'm following the "Sci-fi Crate Design" tutorial from BlenderBros. The tutorial guy created a cutter in the previous video (which can be seen sitting on top of the base of the crate in screen shot 1 below) and then applies the boolean modifier (ss 2) by <kbd>shift</kbd> selecting both objects to perform a slicing operation between the two objects.

After this, the slicing line can be seen between the two objects in his viewport in the screenshot and he is also able to select the two objects separately.

But when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Num /</kbd> to apply the boolean for the slicing operation like he does I cannot select the cutter and the crate separately as they have become one object now. Also there's no slicing as can be seen in the ss 3.

Amateur here. Any leads as to why this is happening would be much appreciated. Also - the tutor is using Blender v2.8 and I'm using v2.9 if that's a problem?

[image: Screenshot 1]
[image: Screenshot 2]
[image: Screenshot 3 - My viewport]

Comment: Have you looked at the Q&A section on the course? - There seems to be a very similar question there which someone sorted by flipping the normals on the cutter. - "Problem with slicing (crate 1: 16. Slicing the Top and Bottom)"

Comment: For what it's worth, I've just done that part of the course in both 2.83 and 2.90.1 and both worked fine. Can you upload your blend file so we can see what's going on please. [link](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/)

Comment: Yeah it was the flipped normals. Thank you so much.

Comment: Glad to hear it's sorted!